# Print middle word in a string. C programming

Tags: c, string, tokenize

I need help on code that print out a middle word of string.

First Example:

> Input:  My name is Alex
>
> Output: either name or is <-- is the middle

Second Example:

> Input:  Hello. I Need help on my coding.
>
> Output: Help <-- middle word

Hopefully someone can help me out. I will try to follow up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(){
char str[] = "good men to come to the aid of their country";
char delims[] = " ";
char *result;
char word[100][100];
int loop=1;
result = strtok(str, delims );
strcpy(word[0],result);
while( result != NULL ) {
    loop++;

    strcpy(word[loop],result);
     result = strtok( NULL, delims );

   }
int mid=loop/2-1;
// to print the middle element
printf("word is %s \n",word[mid+1]);
getch();
return 0;
```

Comment: The only thing I would add here is a case that checks to see if size%2 == 1 (i.e. the case where there is only 1 middle word weresus 2 middle words)

Comment: i add all the header but i cant compile and run? whats wrong?

Comment: 13 C:\Users\Fufu\Documents\middle.cpp `input' undeclared (first use this function)
  (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)

Comment: input string means the string of which you want to find the mid element.

Comment: output i got is 0 . (
can we use something like  
printf("ENTER A STRING...: ");
gets(str);
or is there another easy way to do? sorry for the trouble.

Comment: i got the output for every word.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an idea:

1. Split string into words
2. Now that you know how many words there are, decide how to handle the even case
3. Print the decided words

You can use `strtok()` for the splitting, and perhaps assume that a "typical" sentence has not more than 50 words, each being no longer than 16 characters. Just to simplify the code.

Comment: @trumpetlicks I wrote it in parallel. It happens a lot. I also think it describes a simpler and clearer solution, your "check to see if there are any more tokens" action is not very well described in my opinion, and never needed in mine.

Comment: @trumpetlicks To be frank, unwind's answer has more clarity than yours. This is probably why his answer has been upvoted more.